# Play MP3 files using loops

Tags: excel, vba, mp3

I am working on a code that would play MP3 files from a specific directory based on a list of the file names of these mp3 files in column A. The code works fine for about five or six files then excel hangs for some time then resume from another unexpected point. How can I fix the code so as to make it play all the mp3 files in column A?

```
Public wmp As Object

Sub Test()
    Dim r As Long
    Set wmp = CreateObject("new:6BF52A52-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6")
    For r = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        With wmp
            .URL = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Media\" & Cells(r, 1).Value & ".mp3"
            .Controls.Play
        End With
        DoEvents
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: I have deleted my answer. Will post a detailed answer later with a full example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the loop to build your playlist, then play it

```
Public wmp As Object

Sub Test()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim itm
    Set wmp = CreateObject("new:6BF52A52-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6")
    For r = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        With wmp
            Set itm = .newMedia(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Media\" & Cells(r, 1).Value & ".mp3")
            .currentPlaylist.appendItem itm
        End With
    Next r
    wmp.Controls.Play
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for solution. Can I let waiting between each file?

Comment: No problem. Can't see why not, but why would you need it to wait?

Comment: I need to wait as the code designed to give a student a while of waiting while he is listening to each mp3 file (he needs some time to rest)

Comment: Oh, so you want it to wait before it PLAYS the next file, rather than wait before it ADDS the next file to the playlist, is that correct?

Comment: Not sure if it's possible to pause between tracks like this. For a fixed-length pause between tracks, you could record X seconds of silence and then create your playlist so that it plays this "silent" track after every file. Alternatively, you can give user control over when to play the next track.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great help.